# Excel Validation List Increase Font Size

Tags: excel, vba

Is is possible to increase the font size of an Excel Validation List via a macro?

If not is there an useful workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by default

But yes there is a straightforward workaround. See Debra Dagleish's sample [here at her Contextures site](http://www.contextures.com/xldataval08.html#Larger) - a very thorough reference for Data Validation.

Comment: That looks promising. My problem now is how to Add this Event to A Worksheet. I got Some Worksheets and an Macro xlm Wich contains all the Macros for the sheets. Since i can't access each Sheet separately (more than 700 of these) i need a way to add this in my existing macro file.

Comment: @TheJoeIaut sorry had missed this. I have followed up in your new question

Answer (score 1):

I needed a drop down list in column E to be larger to be readable. The following macro zooms to 100% if I click on any cell in column E past E4 and then goes back to my preferred zoom of 70% when I click anywhere else.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 5 And (Target.Row >= 1 And Target.Row >= 5) Then
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100

    Else
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: N.B. You can use `If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E1:E5")) Is Nothing Then` to check if the target range overlaps the range you are monitoring. Slightly more idiomatic I think.