# Eventcode via macro

Tags: excel, vba, events

I have a lot of Excel sheets (>700, too many to change by hand) and a macro xlm which contains most of the macros for all the sheets. I have functions to loop through all sheets and execute macros in each of those. Because of a request I need to add an Eventhandler via the central macro. Since my understanding of VBA is that a Eventhandler can only be placed in the worksheet code file in the sheet itself I don't now what to do next.

I hope there is a way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event handler can be in any class module.

Your addin also has sheets, in one of those, you can place:

```
Private WithEvents xlApp As Excel.Application
```

Then you will have `xlApp` in the left dropdown and the events in the right one. Select the ones you want.

Don't forget to set `xlApp` to something at some point (for example, to `ThisWorkbook.Application`).

A random reading from Google: [Events And Event Procedures In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx).

Comment: Does this also work for non application Events? For Example if the selected cells are changed.

Answer (score 1):

If the Event is identical for all sheets then running with the `Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` approach suggested by GSerg makes the most sense

You can also add the code to each sheet programmatically - which might be useful if you want to add different "trigger" cells to different sheets based on the sheet names/index.

To add the [Data Validation](http://www.contextures.com/xldataval08.html#Larger) code from your prior question [Excel Validation List Increase Font Size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8940898/641067) you could use this. The code skips normal code modules and the `ThisWorkbook` module

```
Sub DumpCode()
    Const vbext_ct_document = 100
    Dim vbProj As Object
    Dim vbComp As Object
    Dim strTxt As String

    strTxt = "Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)" & vbNewLine _
           & "If Target.Address = ""$A$2"" Then" & vbNewLine _
           & "ActiveWindow.Zoom = 120" & vbNewLine _
           & "Else" & vbNewLine _
           & "ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100" & vbNewLine _
           & "End If" & vbNewLine _
           & "End Sub"

    Set vbProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    For Each vbComp In vbProj.vbcomponents
        If vbComp.Type = vbext_ct_document Then
            If vbComp.Name <> "ThisWorkbook" Then vbComp.CodeModule.InsertLines vbComp.CodeModule.CountOfLines + 1, strTxt
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```